# Error when copying data from Azure Blob Storage to SQL Server using Azure Data Factory V2

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

When triggering my Azure Data Factory V2 pipeline, I receive the following error message:

```
{
    "errorCode": "2109",
    "message": "Region detection for linked services with type 'SqlServer' is not supported, please specify location instead.",
    "failureType": "UserError",
    "target": "Staging"
    }
```

My Azure Data Factory V2 has "westeurope" as its location, and so does the blob storage with the original data.

All linked services in the Data Factory are validated. When I press 'Validate all', my factory also claims to be without mistakes.

What could the source of my error be and how do I fix it?

[image: Output list of my Copy task]

Answer (score 0):

To address this issue you must create an Azure Integration Runtime and give it a correct location. Official documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-integration-runtime#azure-integration-runtime and here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-integration-runtime#integration-runtime-location

To do this you can use Powershell with Azure SDK, the command is Set-AzureRmDataFactoryv2IntegrationRuntime. It has a lot of parameters but you must make sure you create it with -Type Managed.

Example:

```
Set-AzureRmDataFactoryV2IntegrationRuntime -DataFactoryName $DataFactoryName -Name "AzureIR" -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Type Managed -Location "West Europe"
```

After you create this, make sure you reference this in the connectVia property of your linked service for the azure sql.

Hope this helped!